# Multiple graphql queries in Gatsby component

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I need to run multiple graphQL queries within a component and within the `gatsby-node.js` file. (Because Prismic is limited to 20 entries per answer...)

I tried the following, just to see if I could create the graphql loop in the default function:

```
export default () => {
  async function allPosts() {
    let data

    await graphql(`
      query allDitherImages {
        prismic {
          allProjects(sortBy: meta_firstPublicationDate_DESC) {
            totalCount
            pageInfo {
              startCursor
              endCursor
              hasNextPage
              hasPreviousPage
            }
            edges {
              node {
                cover_image
                cover_imageSharp {
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `).then(initialRes => {
      data = initialRes
    })

    return data
  }

  allPosts().then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  return null
}
```

But then Gatsby tells me that `Gatsby related 'graphql' calls are supposed to only be evaluated at compile time, and then compiled away. Unfortunately, something went wrong and the query was left in the compiled code.`

How can I run multiple graphql queries?

Thank you in advance :) 
Michael

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-fetching/ .... you can/should fetch (accumulate) all data (in loop) in gatsby-node.js

Answer (score 1):

The [gatsby-source-prismic-graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql) package will create pages for all of your Prismic items (more than just the first 20), as it iterates over all items under the hood, so I'd advise looking into using that if you are looking to generate pages for all of those items.

But if you need to get all items and pass them in the pageContext or something, you'll need to do the recursion yourself in the gatsby-node.

In the gatsby-node, after you have defined the query, you can use something like this to iterate over the results and push to an array.

```
let documents = [];
async function getAllDocumentsRecursively (query, prop, endCursor = '') {
  const results = await graphql(query, { after: endCursor })
  const hasNextPage = results.data.prismic[prop].pageInfo.hasNextPage
  endCursor = results.data.prismic[prop].pageInfo.endCursor

  results.data.prismic[prop].edges.forEach(({node}) => {
    documents.push(node)
  });

  if (hasNextPage) {
    await getAllDocumentsRecursively(query, 'allDitherImages ', endCursor)
  }
}
await getAllDocumentsRecursively(documentsQuery, 'allDitherImages ');
```

Then in your createPage, pass the array into the context:

```
createPage({
    path: `/`+ node._meta.uid,
    component: allDitherTempate,
    context: {
      documents: documents
    }
  })
```